# Cant write a value to a txt file in r+ mode with either fwrite() or fprintf

Tags: c, file

Okay so i get some values from the user and then i save them to a txt file called orders.txt
and it looks like this

```
Marios22    100.000000  3000.000000 Sat Dec 10 18:20:32 `F!v
```

This is the function which i use to get my values and write to

```
struct order RegisterOrder(){
    FILE *ft;
    struct order o;
    time_t temp;
    char temp1[20];

    printf("Enter the name of the customer:");
    scanf("%s",&o.onoma);
    printf("Enter The number of the small bottles:\n");
    scanf("%f",&o.smallbnum);
    printf("Enter The number of the big bottles:\n");
    scanf("%f",&o.bigbnum);
    
    time(&temp);   // dinei to execution date
    
    strcpy(o.executiondate,ctime(&temp));

    ft=fopen("orders.txt","a"); // creates and opens a file called orders.txt
    fprintf(ft,"%s\t%f\t%f\t%s\n", o.onoma, o.smallbnum, o.bigbnum, o.executiondate);
    fclose(ft);

    return o;
}
```

Now next i want to call the CalculateCost() function in order to calculate o.cost and write it into the txt file but it doesnt work and reamains unchanged

```
struct order calculateCost(struct order o){
    float discount;
    float finalcost;
    float smallbnum, bigbnum;
    FILE *ft;
    ft=fopen("orders.txt", "r+"); 
    fscanf(ft,"%f %f", &o.smallbnum, &o.bigbnum);

    o.cost=(o.smallbnum*SMALLPRICE + o.bigbnum*BIGPRICE);

    if (o.cost>600)
        discount=0.2;
    else if ((o.cost>200)|| (o.bigbnum+o.smallbnum>3000)){
        discount=0.08;}

        finalcost = o.cost *(1-discount);
        o.cost=finalcost;

        fprintf(ft,"%g\t", o.cost);
        //fwrite(&o.cost, sizeof(float), 1, ft);


        printf("The cost is:%f\n",finalcost);
        fclose(ft);

        return o;

    
}
```

I tried for example: r+ mode/ a+ mode or using

```
fwrite(&o.cost, sizeof(float), 1, ft);
```

or

```
fprintf(ft,"%g\t", o.cost);
```

but i just cant get it to write anything

Comment: Between reading and writing a file opened in + mode, you have to call `fseek()`, `fsetpos()`, or `rewind()`. Details at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen

Comment: I see, this is my first exercise with files so i didnt know that, i will try keeping that in mind and fix it

Comment: Update: i used  ```fseek(ft, 0, SEEK_END);``` and it wrote this in the file w�_B, im pretty confused can someone help me out - i was in a+ mode btw

Comment: Your [posted] code is: `ft=fopen("orders.txt", "r+"); // reading and appending mode` Per `man fopen`: `r+` is _not_ "open for reading and appending" mode. It is "open for reading and writing". `a+` is "open for reading and appending".

Comment: yea i tried using a+ mode before switching to r+ in hope of fixing it but i just forgot to delete the comment ignore it